# Proving a set is Borel (Related to Binary Expansions)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the subsets of $[0,1]$, given by:
$$
S_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: \text{The $\textbf{Binary}$ expansion of $x$ has a $1$ in the $n$th position}\}
$$
How can I prove these sets are open/closed/Borel? I suspect they are closed, but am at a loss as to how this can be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try the $n=2$ case to see what's happening. Then $x\in S_2$ if and only if \begin{equation}x\in [0.01,0.02)\cup [0.11,0.12)\cup\ldots\cup [.91,.92).
\end{equation}
Why is this Borel? How can you generalize this to larger $n$?

This evidently isn't closed as written above, but it slightly depends on your convention on decimal expansions. The decimal expansion is defined uniquely up to repeating $9$s at the end, i.e. $0.02=0.01999\ldots$. If this is meant to be included in the definition of $S_n$, then you should change the above appropriately. Is it closed then?

Comment: I just realized this, but I meant to say BINARY, rather than decimal. My bad :/ I think the technique would be similar...

Comment: It's exactly the same. The point is that the set is just a union of a finite number of intervals, which you can even explicitly write out. For $n=2$ in binary, you can see this is $[1/4,1/2)\cup [3/4,1)$, at least with the convention that $1/2=0.1$ in binary, not $0.011111111\ldots$. If you need more help, note that each interval in the union is a translate of the set $[2^{-n},2^{-n+1})$, so try writing it that way.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you